# How to make a SPARKLINE with text (data label) in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-sparkline

I want to create a `=SPARKLINE()` with the parameters `{"charttype", "bar"}` with a text in the same cell as the chart. How is it possible?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not an option. More here https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/sparkline-line-chart-formula-options/

Comment: How do you want the text to look there may be other solutions to accomplishing what you need. Please give a very specific example of how you want the output to look.

Answer (score 3):

> Google Sheets creates sparklines via formulas so **it's not possible to
> have the value and the sparkline bar at the same cell**. You can put
> them in adjacent cells and remove the border so it'll look like they
> are at the same cell but that's it, unfortunately.

Source:
 https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/dbf9os/sparkline_text